# Is it possible to setup timeout for receiving data over USB in STM32 MCUs?

Tags: timeout, usb, stm32, hal

I'm wondering if this is possible to setup a timeout for receiving data over USB interface in STM32 microcontrollers. Such approach is possible for example in UART connection (please refer to AN3109, section 2. Receive DMA timeout).

I can't find anything similar related to USB interface. What's more, it is said that DMA for USB should be enabled only if really necessary because data transfer shall be aligned to 32-bit word.

Comment: To be honest I do no understand what your problem is.  USB is 100 master slave and your device only reacts on the host commands. In HAL internal operations are timeouted. You do not need to worry.

Comment: I'm trying to find a solution to receive packets with different number of bytes in size. The interface is USB VCP. Since I don't know what exactly the size of the message is I want to setup some interrupt, some kind of RX inactive timeout. When interrupt is triggered, I know that the host ended sending the message and MCU can start processing it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a receive call back function (if you use the HAL) in your ...._if.c file. Copy reived chars to the buffer. Implement timeout there.

Answer (score 0):

What you refer to in case of UART is either DMA receive timeout as you've said or (when not using DMA) an IDLE interrupt. I'm not aware of such thing coming "out of the box" for USB CDC - you'd have to implement this timeout yourself, which shouldn't be too hard. Have a timer (hardware of software) that you re-trigger every time you receive data. Set its period to the timeout value of your choice and do protocol parsing after timeout elapses.

If I had to add anything - these kind of problems (not knowing how many bytes to receive) are typically solved at the protocol level. Assuming binary protocol, one way of achieving this is having frame start and end bytes which never occur in data (and if they do - you escape them) in which case you receive everything starting after "start byte" until you reveive "end byte". Yet another way is having a "start byte" and a field indicating how many bytes there are to receive. All of it should of course be checksumed in some way.

Having said that, if you have an option to change the protocol, you *really* should do so. Relying on timings in your communication, especially on such low level only invites problems and headaches in the long run. You introduce tight coupling between your protocol layer and interface layer. This is going to backfire on you every time you decide to use a different interface, as you'll have to re-invent the same thing again. Not to mention how painful it's going to be when you decide to move to TCP/IP with all its greatness - network jitter, dropped packets etc.

Comment: Yeah, that's another approach which I've been using in low data rate UART connection. I'm just receiving few first bytes without DMA, then I can check for bytes number field and setup RX DMA transfer. Although in the case of high speed interfaces, such as USB, let's say "manually" receiving first bytes without DMA is a little bit tricky in terms of CPU usage. With high data rate in USB, we can't event be sure that MCU will be capable to receive bytes one by one.

Comment: Adding SOF and EOF frames with predefined patterns would be great, but we can't change IP hardware in MCU, it works as it works and I'm afraid there's no such feature in STM32. But maybe I'm wrong...

Do you have any examples of such approach in STM32 MCUs in terms of USB and SPI interfaces so I could learn more?

Comment: What are you asking for exactly? If you're asking about how to implement such protocol, this is what "protocol design" is about and is a whole big branch on its own where a single Stack Overflow comment or an answer isn't going to be sufficient.

Comment: I'm creating a simple debug protocol and trying to figure out simple solution to cope with "don't know exact number of bytes" on STM32 MCUs and USB/SPI interfaces. At this moment relying on idle timeout seems to be the best option here. The question is how to have it done with exisiting resources on that MCU. As I mentioned about AN3109, that's quite easy with UART interface, but not with USB.
There is always some bonding between physical interface and protocol.

Comment: I'd argue whether "there is always some bonding" - as long as the abstraction presented to the protocol layer is the same, i.e. bytes are received and they may or may not come in batches, delayed and so on, at that point it really doesn't matter what the interface actually is. It could as well be a piece of wet string. If you can confirm that the received bytes haven't been corrupted and you collected them all, it should work.

Comment: As for implementation you're asking for - personally if I was to create something quickly just for some kind of debugging I'd go with [STX][frame data][checksum][ETX]. Three special value bytes (STX=`0x02`, ETX=`0x03` and ESC=`0x1B`). If any byte in frame data or checksum equals to one of those 3 special bytes, you escape it: prepend it with ESC and XOR its value with something (let's say XOR with ESC also). When receiving you receive from STX to ETX while reversing the XOR-ing. After that verify checksum.

Comment: ...and how do you want to include DMA here? MCU doesn't receive bytes one by one, just setups a DMA transfer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195795/discussion-between-jacek-slimok-and-vipper).